# How do stacked denoising autoencoders work

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, learning-algorithms, recommender-system

I've been studying a recommender system which uses a collaborative deep learning approach and Bayesian learning. It has the following NN representation :

[image: sdae]

I need to know the working of stacked denoising autoencoders.

Here is the link to the paper:http://www.wanghao.in/paper/KDD15_CDL.pdf